# How to create a report in XLS or CSV without accessing server

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

Generally when I'm asked to generate a report (for example a simple ASCII/CSV file) by means of a select from a table, I've always used the UTL_FILE for writing every row into a file on the server.
Let's suppose I don't have an access to a server. In this case, how can I write a procedure for generating the report directly on the database into a BLOB/CLOB colum of a table? Is it possible?

Oracle version 10g

Thanks in advance!

Mark

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store output into a `CLOB` column (don't use `BLOB`; result of a `SELECT` statement isn't *binary*), one option might be this:

Sample table and a sequence:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE test
  2  (
  3     id    NUMBER,
  4     col   CLOB
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE seq_test;

Sequence created.
```

PL/SQL procedure that fetches data row-by-row and concatenates it to already existing data:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_col  CLOB;
  3     l_id   NUMBER := seq_test.NEXTVAL;
  4  BEGIN
  5     FOR cur_r IN (SELECT deptno, dname, loc FROM dept)
  6     LOOP
  7        l_col :=
  8              l_col
  9           || cur_r.deptno
 10           || ';'
 11           || cur_r.dname
 12           || ';'
 13           || cur_r.loc
 14           || CHR (10);
 15     END LOOP;
 16
 17     INSERT INTO test (id, col)
 18          VALUES (l_id, l_col);
 19  END;
 20  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM test;

        ID COL
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1 10;ACCOUNTING;NEW YORK
           20;RESEARCH;DALLAS
           30;SALES;CHICAGO
           40;OPERATIONS;BOSTON


SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work but when I try to export the result in CSV or TXT I get some unexpected question marks inside the file:
"10;ACCOUNTING;NEW YORK
20;RESEARCH;DALLAS
30;SALES;CHICAGO
40;OPERATIONS;BOSTON"

Comment: Question marks? I didn't get any. Could it be because of different NLS settings in your database and operating system, so - when you checked the result - you got "wrong" output? For example, characters like đšžćč that don't exist in English (or whichever language you might be using).